# TiKz drawing as a symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I drew a symbol using tikz. Let's say it's a cross like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}    
      \draw[<->]  (-5,0) -- (5,0); 
      \draw[<->]  (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I would like to use my graph as icon. For example icon like `\circ`. I would like to use it in normal text and in enumerate environment. Is it possible?

EDIT:

Thank you, it works! I have a problem with scale now, because my drawing is a bit different:

```
\def\myicon{
\scalerel*{
\begin{tikzpicture}    
      \draw[l<->]  (-5,0) -- (5,0); 
      \draw[<->]  (0,-5) -- (0,5);
      \draw[<->]  ({-5*sin(45)},{-5*cos(45)})  -- ({5*sin(45)},{5*cos(45)});
      \draw[<->]  ({-5*sin(45)},{5*cos(45)})  -- ({5*sin(45)}, {-5*cos(45)});
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
```

But I will try to find a solution with this package.

Comment: Your edit does not have the proper `scalerel` syntax.  Try this: `\def\mycross{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}    
      \draw[<->]  (-5,0) -- (5,0); 
      \draw[<->]  (0,-5) -- (0,5);
      \draw[<->]  ({-5*sin(45)},{-5*cos(45)})  -- ({5*sin(45)},{5*cos(45)});
      \draw[<->]  ({-5*sin(45)},{5*cos(45)})  -- ({5*sin(45)}, {-5*cos(45)});
\end{tikzpicture}}{X}}` . Note that `\scalerel` takes two arguments.  Plus, there is a stray  `l` (ell) in your `\draw` command.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly, but unfortunantely this symbol is not adjusted for this sizes. Nevertheless, thanks for help.

Comment: The size that it is adjusted to is the `X` at the end of the definition.  If you want it adjusted to a different size, you can place something else instead of the  `X` to scale it to.  Alternately, you can look up the syntax for `\scaleto`, which scales something to a specified size, rather than to the size of some object.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I think that arrowhead in this sizes is just to small to be visible and I think that's it's impossible to do it if I want it to look nice.

Comment: Just change your `5` values to something smaller, such as `0.3`.  See my edit.

Comment: Woah, thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I make `\mycross` fit the vertical footprint of a paren pair `()`, but you can change the scale-to character(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\mycross{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}    
      \draw[<->]  (-5,0) -- (5,0); 
      \draw[<->]  (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}}{()}}
\begin{document}
XYZ\mycross pdq

\begin{itemize}[label=\mycross]
\item First
\item Next
\item Last
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here it is with the scale-to character set to a cap `X`:

[image]

---

Here, with the OP's EDIT, which had some syntax issues.  I also scaled down the base size of the `tikzpicture`, so as to bring out the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\mycross{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}    
      \draw[<->]  (-.3,0) -- (.3,0); 
      \draw[<->]  (0,-.3) -- (0,.3);
      \draw[<->]  ({-.3*sin(45)},{-.3*cos(45)})  -- ({.3*sin(45)},{.3*cos(45)});
      \draw[<->]  ({-.3*sin(45)},{.3*cos(45)})  -- ({.3*sin(45)}, {-.3*cos(45)});
\end{tikzpicture}}{X}}
\begin{document}
XYZ\mycross pdq

\begin{itemize}[label=\mycross]
\item First
\item Next
\item Last
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you see my edit? Maybe you know the way how to scale it good. But, I will try too.